# Laravel FTPES connection

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

I have to connect to FTP server through FTPES protocol in Laravel 8 (PHP 8.0).
I made configuration like:

```
'ftpes' => [
    'driver'   => 'ftp',
    'host'     => 'ftpes://ftp.page.com',
    'username' => 'login',
    'password' => 'password',
    'port'     => 21,
    'passive'  => true,
    'ssl'      => true,
]
```

But every time I try to connect to this server I get error:

> Could not connect to host: ftpes://ftp.page.com, port:21

With FileZilla I can connect there without any errors.

---

Edit:
Removed `ftpes://` and added `'ignorePassiveAddress' => true` to filesystem config and it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ftpes://` is not a part of the hostname, drop it.

Comment: After modification I have another error:
`ftp_rawlist(): php_connect_nonb() failed: No error (0)`

Edit:
Adding also 'ignorePassiveAddress' => true
resolves the problem